# How to reduce the margin size for piechart in achartengine?

Tags: java, javascript, android, performance, android-intent

I am using a-chartengine for drawing pie chart. I am not able reduce the size of the pie chart margins. I want to reduce the margin layout which is default,But the size of pie chart should not get reduce. I have used setMargin() function. It don't have any effect on it.

If anyone know the solution please help me.

My output screen:
http://postimg.org/image/gh6gvpq7h/

[image]

My Output should be:
http://postimg.org/image/bnozxqgk3/

[image]

My code:

```
  RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pie_graph_layout);
  //System.out.println("We are in chart");
  mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
  mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false); 
  mRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
  mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
  mRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
  //mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20 ,60,  -20, 60 });
  //mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -25, 20, -25, 40 })
  piechartview = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
```

Comment: My code in Java:

      mRenderer.setScale(1.5f); // <----- Here is the change.
      piechartview = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);

My code in xml:[this is the layout i am using for draw the piechart]

               <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/pie_graph_layout"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can try this code.

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
  par.height = 20; 
  par.width = 10; 
  View.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right u can use  LayoutParams to adjust, use ur type of params

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
//        params.height = 200;
//        params.width = 100;
        mChartView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

U may have to change few other values of params.

Comment: I find out the solution myself. Your are partially right. We can adjust the layout by height and width. But the chart size will also reduce. What i did ?. I have scaled the pie chart using
      mRenderer.setScale(1.3f); // used for scaling the graph
to adjust the size.